# Offset UL by 100px if the dynamic list only has 3 LI

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic image carousel that holds 3 images in view, 1 full image with 2 either side that are cutoff IF there is more than 3.. which is fine but i'm looking for a way to offset the UL to the left if it ONLY has 3 images.. it currently shows 2 images split across the screen but neither are centered. so basically I want to identify a UL and if there is only 3 li offset to the left by 100px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $carousel = $('#carousel');
var $ul = $carousel.find('ul');
var $lis = $ul.find('li');

if ($lis.length === 3) {
    $ul.css('margin-left', '-100px');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if 3 li exits in your dynamic carousel, you'll need to do the following code:

```
var len = $("#yourcontainer li").length;

if(len == 3) {

// Only 3 LIs

}

</script>
```

where #yourcontainer is the immediate or a bit above level in DOM parent of the li's you want to count. Len will have the number of li's under #yourcontainer. Then we check if len = 3, then a conditional command can be executed, anything you want.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?